# How to snap to a line or extend a straight line in QGIS?

Tags: polygon, qgis-3, line, splitting, snapping

I have one object in my layer, which includes a line segment in itself as part of the overall polygon. I would like to create another line by extending this line outward, in order to cut another object using the same line segment. Here's an example:

Using that small red line segment I highlighted on the left over there, I want to be able to extend that, through the purple dotted area, and ultimately onto the green line that I've indicated. The end goal is to split that brown object on the right, along an exact extension of that original segment, of course.

P.S. Needless to say, it would be easy for me to turn that red segment into a line feature of its own. The issue is how to make it longer, enough to at least cover the distance spanned by the brown object on the right.

[image: map]

Comment: A possible workflow with tools from the processing toolbox. 1. Select polygon, run `Polygons to lines` with 'Selected features only' checked. 2. `Explode Lines` on result 3. If required, (depending on line direction), select desired line and run `Reverse line direction` with 'Selected features only' checked 4. Run `Extend lines` on result.